# Google Sheets - Select rows which not contain specific words

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I had a Google form where people have selected options from a check list. e.g.

```
[] London / Manchester
[] Hong Kong
[] Paris
[] Rome
[] Other: [text]
```

My responses are in Google Sheets. Some people have selected options 1 to 4 as well as   'Other' and typed their message, e.g.

```
London / Manchester, Paris, I want to go to Tokyo
London / Manchester, Hong Kong
Paris, Singapore please
Amsterdam
```

How do I query my spreadsheet to select rows where people have typed a message in the Other option. Hence, the only rows that should show are:

```
London / Manchester, Paris, I want to go to Tokyo
Paris, Singapore please
Amsterdam
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**:
Alternatively, can I somehow filter out the rows using a list of keywords so it only shows text that was entered for Other?

So if a column had these values below, can I use a keyword list such as 'London / Manchester', 'Paris', 'Hong Kong' and 'Rome' to hide these rows but show if text was added to Other option?

```
London / Manchester, Paris, I want to go to Tokyo
London / Manchester, Hong Kong
Paris, Singapore please
Amsterdam
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(A:A,len(regexreplace(A:A," ?(London / Manchester|Hong Kong|Paris|Rome),?",""))))
```

[image]

If you wanted to add more columns, you could either just put them in the filter e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(A:C,len(regexreplace(A:A," ?(London / Manchester|Hong Kong|Paris|Rome),?",""))))
```

or in a query e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A:C,len(regexreplace(A:A," ?(London / Manchester|Hong Kong|Paris|Rome),?",""))},"select Col1,Col2, Col3 where Col4>0"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - Is there a way combine the ArrayFormula with Query so I can show other columns i.e. first name, last name etc?

Comment: Will add to my answer

Answer (score 0):

if column Other is D column you can try:

```
=QUERY(A:D; "where D is not null"; )
```

Comment: Other is not a separate column. All values selected from the list of options are saved in one column, comma separated.

Comment: I've updated the post with a alternative solution if it's can be done. Thanks